# Deleting Parent setting Child values to NULL not deleting them

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have an `User` entity which has a list of roles.
When I delete the `user` I expect the children roles to be deleted too.
However the foreign key is just set to null and its not deleted. Can you please explain why this behaviour is occurring. I added `CascadeType.ALL` which I thought would delete the child roles.

**User.java**

```
@SerializedName("userrole")
@Expose
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Role> userRoles = new ArrayList<Role>();
```

**Role.java**

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long     id;

@NotNull
private RoleEnum role;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "user")
private User     user;
```

**Table after delete**

```
+----+------+------+
| id | role | user |
+----+------+------+
|  1 |    0 | NULL |
|  2 |    1 | NULL |
|  3 |    2 | NULL |
|  4 |    3 | NULL |
|  5 |    4 | NULL |
|  6 |    5 | NULL |
|  7 |    6 | NULL |
|  8 |    7 | NULL |
+----+------+------+
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please don't do `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` from `Role.user`. You probably don't want to delete the user in case one of it's roles is deleted.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @NándorElődFekete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with `orphanRemoval` attribute. Quoting the relevant part from the JPA 2.0 Spec.

> Associations that are specified as OneToOne or OneToMany support use of the orphanRemoval
>   option. The following behaviors apply when orphanRemoval is in effect:
>
> If an entity that is the target of the relationship is removed from the relationship (by setting the
>   relationship to null or removing the entity from the relationship collection), the remove operation
>   will be applied to the entity being orphaned. The remove operation is applied at the time of
>   the flush operation. The orphanRemoval functionality is intended for entities that are privately
>   "owned" by their parent entity. Portable applications must otherwise not depend upon a
>   specific order of removal, and must not reassign an entity that has been orphaned to another
>   relationship or otherwise attempt to persist it. If the entity being orphaned is a detached, new,
>   or removed entity, the semantics of orphanRemoval do not apply.
>
> If the remove operation is applied to a managed source entity, the remove operation will be
>   cascaded to the relationship target in accordance with the rules of section 3.2.3, (and hence it is
>   not necessary to specify cascade=REMOVE for the relationship

So your `OneToMany` annotation will look like,

`@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)`